# Apply custom function to elements by class in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Probably another stupid question but I thought this was how you do it...

I have a function which includes making an element visible and then animating it onto the stage. I would like to a apply this to an element with the class '.start' to begin with, and then to some other elements throughout the project.

```
function showthis() {
    $(this).show().css({ "display": "block" }).animate({ "top": "40px" }, "fast");
    console.log('THIS IS: ' + this);
};

$('.start').showthis();
```

OR

```
showthis('.start');
```

If I use the first way I get an error saying 'showthis isn't a function'. And with the second way I just get 'THIS IS: [object Window]' in the console

Pretty sure I'm making a newbie error so all help will be appreciated.

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 1):

Try extending like

```
(function($){
    $.fn.showthis = function() {
         this.show().animate({ "top": "40px" }, "fast");
         return this;//for method chaining - $('.start').showthis().append()...
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Then you should be able to call like `$('.start').showthis();` Notice, above `$(this)` is not needed because `showthis` is part of the same object that has `show()`, so `this` itself will suffice.

See [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

If you do not wish to extend, then you will have to fix showthis by using a passed in selector or passing in the jQuery object itself

```
function showthis(selector) {
     $(selector).show().animate({ "top": "40px" }, "fast");
};
```

and then call like `showthis('.start');`

P.S: Notice, `.css('display','block')` was removed because it is the same as `.show()`

Comment: a `return this;` would be nice here, because of the method-chaining ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function showthis(obj) {

     $(obj).show().css({ "display" : "block" } ).animate({ "top": "40px" }, "fast");
     console.log('THIS IS: '+ obj);

};

 showthis('.start');
```